# Java - How to exit a do while loop?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader ();
    double money = 0; //Cash Variable
    int Choice = 0; //Menu Choice
    Scanner AccountIn = new Scanner(System.in);  //Scanner for AccountNumbers
    ArrayList<String> AccountNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    String accountValue = "";
    int x = 1;

    do{     
        try{   
            System.out.println("Create Account Number");
            accountValue = AccountIn.nextLine();
            if(accountValue.length()>7 && accountValue.length()<9){
                // EveryTime AccountNumber Is created store in Array
                AccountNumber.add(accountValue); //ADD USER INPUT 
                money = reader.readDouble("Enter Starting Amount Of Money");
                do { 
                    System.out.println("1.Deposit");
                    System.out.println("2.Withdraw");
                    System.out.println("3.View Account Details");
                    System.out.println("4.Exit");
                    Choice = reader.readInt(""); //Selects Choice
                    switch (Choice) {
                    case 1:
                        //Money is incremented by the amount listed 
                        money+=reader.readDouble();
                        System.out.println("Current Amount" + money); 
                        break;

                    case 2: 
                        money -= reader.readDouble();
                        System.out.println("Curent Amount" + money);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        System.out.println(AccountNumber);
                        System.out.println("Final Amount:" + money);
                    }
                } while(Choice != 4); //Exit Do While Loop
                System.out.println("Final Amount:" + money);
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
            }else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Enter Valid Number");
        } 
    } while (x==1);
}
```

I am trying to exit the program if the user enters the number `4` and be displayed with the Final Amount and the message 'Goodbye' only, right now it loops right back to the top displaying the message "Create Account Number".

Comment: Before asking a question about something like this try to do some research, start at Oracle's documentation for example.

Answer (score 1):

add 1 more case after case 3: (add break; to case 3 too)

```
case 4:
   x = 0; // while(x==1) needs to stop, so you need to set it something other than 1, maybe 0.
}
```